# How to configure bro to listen locally instead of on all interfaces?

Tags: networking, configuration, network-interface, ip-address, bro

By default, bro listens on port 47660, that is okay, but I cannot seem to find any option to tell it to only listen on a particular IP or interface.  Is that possible?

I checked here:
https://github.com/bro/broctl/blob/master/etc/node.cfg
https://www.bro.org/sphinx/components/broctl/README.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Quick Start guide](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/quickstart/index.html#managing-bro-with-brocontrol), edit the `interface` option in `$PREFIX/etc/node.cfg`. The full list of options that you can change in this file are found in [the `Node` plugin documentation.](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/components/broctl/README.html#class-node)

Comment: Thanks, but I was following that and don't see anything specific about controlling anything other than the port: https://www.bro.org/sphinx/components/broctl/README.html#class-node

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.bro.org/sphinx/scripts/base/frameworks/communication/main.bro.html, the variable to set is `Communication::listen_interface` in `base/frameworks/communication/main.bro` (or possibly in your `node.cfg`, but I can't figure out how to do that).